# coldfusion and exceeding time limits

Tags: coldfusion

I've got some long and complex code that does a bit of parsing, and takes a while to go through, it doesn't make much sense in this case to optimize the code.

What are the strategies for handling long execution times and letting the user know when it is done?

---

explanation of why it doesn't make much sense to optimize

The application has end-user-facing pages and non-end-user-facing pages. In the non-user facing area I am parsing several excel spreadsheets. Loading and looping through these takes a long time. It I optimize the code to run within my timeout limit it might work today, but a month from now I might be importing a file that's 4 times as long and it won't work yet again. The issue I am trying to solve is getting around the cf timeout for a specific operation that I know takes a long time.

I've tried using threads but for some reason worked on CF9 but not CF8 (though they are supported)

I also just found out about `cfsetting requestTimeOut` which might be able to do what I need to do.

Comment: _"it doesn't make much sense in this case to optimize the code"_ - is that the view of the users or the programmers? :/

Comment: Maybe post a new question with the code in question and see if someone can give advice on how to optimize?

Comment: I had a legacy system a few years ago that had a similar problem. A quick and simple solution was to kick off the processing on a seperate `cfthread` while the main thread updated the page with a message like "Processing...please check back later." Once the cfthread finished, it would update a DB field, and the processing message would dissapear.

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick looks like that might be the way to go. I might try storing a variable at application level and triggering an ajax request every couple of seconds to see if the job finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking to extend the timeout, Ben Nadel has a good post about 'cfsetting requestTimeOut'

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/626-CFSetting-RequestTimeout-Updates-Timeouts-It-Does-Not-Set-Them.htm

this doesn't solve the issue of notifying, but it will render the page once it is done, so it solves my problem

example code that sets multiple timeout levels

```
<!--- Set the current time out to be 3 seconds. --->
<cfsetting requesttimeout="3" />

<!---
    Get the millisecond start time for page processing
    (so that later on, we can check to see how long
    the page ran overall).
--->
<cfset intStart = GetTickCount() />


<!--- Try to kill some time. --->
<cftry>

    <!---
        Here, we are killing time - 4 seconds to be
        approximate. This will exceed the request time
        out set above (3 seconds) and will throw an error.
    --->
    <cfset KillTime( 4000 ) />


    <!--- The KillTime() method call has timed out. --->
    <cfcatch>

        First Timeout!<br />

        <!---
            In an attempt to "recover" from this time out,
            update the request time out to be six seconds.
        --->
        <cfsetting requesttimeout="6" />


        <!--- Try to kill some more time. --->
        <cftry>

            <!---
                We are going to try and kill about four
                seconds. If this is in terms of the six-second
                timeout set above, this should NOT timeout.
                However, if this is in the context of the
                overall page time (including previous kill time
                calls), then this will timeout.
            --->
            <cfset KillTime( 4000 ) />


            <!--- The KillTime() method has timed out. --->
            <cfcatch>

                Second Timeout!<br />

            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>

    </cfcatch>

</cftry>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a legacy system a few years ago that had a similar problem.

On form post, I did two things:

1. I kicked off a `CFTHREAD` to handle the processing.
2. I updated a database field, letting the application know that the job was processing.

That way, anytime the page was viewed, and that database field (or application variable, however you'd like it), was set to `true` I knew to display a message like, "Please check back later, your request is processing."

When the `CFTHREAD` finished, I would update the DB field to `false`, and the page would return to its normal state. In retrospect, an application variable would have been a better solution. If CF was to crash or be restarted, your DB wouldn't falsely be reporting a running process.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably looked into it already, but see if anything could be cached, to reduce the amount of time waiting.

As for communicating it to the user, for starters make sure the user knows when things are happening. One of the worst things a program can do is receive input and not react. Make sure the user is well aware when something is happening. The way you display the loading is up to you. There could be an hourglass of sorts if the loadtime is under roughly ten seconds or so, but if the wait is longer you'll likely want a progress bar or something similar.

If there is any way you can allow some of it to happen in the background or during other processes, that could help ease the load. Otherwise, pop up a suggestion that tells them to go get coffee. :)

This is just a kneejerk response with only a little information, but if you can give more of an idea on what you are looking for and rough load time estimates I could maybe get more specific.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach 1

I had a site on II6 and CF 7. I added this bar graph that was manipulated via Javascript. I would then set the length of the graph via a Javascript followed by a `<cfflush>`.

It worked well until the site got upgraded to II7.5 and CF 9. For some reason `<cfflush>` does not work, the Javascript can still set the bar and give a meaningful progress.

### Approach 2

This requires two iframes.

- One iframe runs the long running process and is hidden from the users view.
- The other iframe runs a page that refreshes every 10 seconds or so. This page queries the back end logging for the slow process. It may be 10 seconds behind, but end users may even notice

### Approach 3

Do the same as approach 2, but with AJAX

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to start your page with something like this:

```
<div id="displayarea">
display something here
</div>
<cfflush>
```

Then do whatever processing you need to do.  Once it's done, do something like this.

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "newdisplay_cf>
generate html here
</cfsavecontent>

<script>
<cfoutput>
var #toScript(newdisplay_cf, "newdisplay_js")#
</cfoutput>
document.getElementById("displayarea").value = newdisplay_js;
</script>
```

There may be some syntax errors here.  I just typed the code into the textarea.